# Ignore or modify request headers in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I need to make NGINX ignore / modify a request header.

Problem is some IoT devices are sending a HEAD request with the wrong Content-Length header. That makes NGINX wait for more content and then timeout.

Both dropping the Content-Length header or setting it to 0 should do the trick.

Example

This fails

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: MY_HOST
Content-Length: 59
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
```

This works (Content-Length: 0)

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: MY_HOST
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
```

This works too (no Content-Length)

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: MY_HOST
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
```

How can I make it happen?

Comment: Would hiding the header with `proxy_hide_header` work for you?

Comment: NGINX is supposed to handle the request itself (i.e. not proxying it). From what I understand that directive works for the proxied request. But could be totally mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there's a NGINX module named [HeadersMore](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_clear_input_headers) that allow modifying input headers (and more).

In particular more_clear_input_headers allows to remove input headers and more_set_input_headers allows to modify input headers.

In my case

```
more_clear_input_headers "Content-Length";
```

or

```
more_set_input_headers "Content-Length: 0";
```

Comment: It's not fully compatible with the latest version of Nginx.